# How do I change the output of Assertion error with python?

Tags: python

On Terminal of Mac OS X.

The output of assertEqual is

```
  File "tests/test_conditions.py", line 27, in test_if_condition
    self.assertEqual(result, expected)
AssertionError: '    if (self) {\n        self.addMainLabel\n        self.addSubLabel\n        self.setupBackground\n    }\n' != '    if self\n        self.addMainLabel\n        self.addSubLabel\n        self.setupBackground\n    end\n'
```

But I'd like to get the following output with evaluating line break '\n' and add line break after 'AssertionError:'.

```
  File "tests/test_conditions.py", line 27, in test_if_condition
    self.assertEqual(result, expected)
AssertionError: 
'    if (self) {
        self.addMainLabel
        self.addSubLabel
        self.setupBackground
    }
' != 
'    if self
        self.addMainLabel
        self.addSubLabel
        self.setupBackground
    end
'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, at least, not easily.

The escaped newlines are coming from `assertEqual` calling `repr` on each of the two strings. Without that, you'd not get the quotations marks either. If either of your strings contained `!=`, it would get very confusing.

If you really do want to fudge the assertion's text, you can catch it, manipulate it's properties and then reraise it. I don't recommend this, but it is possible:

```
try:
    self.assertEquals(result, expected)
except AssertionError as e:
    e.args = (e.args[0].replace("\\n", "\n"),) # edit the exception's message
    raise
```

This doesn't give exactly the output you want (no extra newlines are added at the start of the strings), but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get *similar* output with newlines would be to either call `assertMultiLineEqual` directly for each `str` equality comparison or to register it as a type-specific method for `assertEqual`. You could do the latter by using this in your setup,

```
self.addTypeEqualityFunc(str, 'assertMultiLineEqual')
```

Then when you call `assertEqual` on your two strings you'll get something like,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 10, in test1
    self.assertEqual(result, expected)
AssertionError: '    if (self) {\n        self.addMainLabel\n        self.addSubLabel\n        s [truncated]... != '    if self\n        self.addMainLabel\n        self.addSubLabel\n        self. [truncated]...
-     if (self) {
?        -    ---
+     if self
          self.addMainLabel
          self.addSubLabel
          self.setupBackground
-     }
+     end
```

`unittest` uses [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) so that the output highlights the places where the two strings differ, which you may or may not find preferable.

Comment: `assertMultiLineEqual` works well. But I'm sorry, I didn't mention about python versions. I need to do it with python 2.6 and python 3.3 for Sublime Text plugins.